# parse query doesnotmatch point pfuser

Tags: swift, parse-platform, point

I have develop a friend relationship app, user can add exist user as friend.
Then I am doing a search friend function, my table structure like below:
PFUser --> record current user(standard class)
FriendList --> username(my user name), friend(point for PFUser)

when user add relation:

```
        var friendListObject = PFObject(className: "FriendList")
        friendListObject.setObject(currentUser!.username!, forKey: "myusername")
        friendListObject.setObject(result.user, forKey: "friend") //result.user = PFUser
        friendListObject.saveInBackgroundWithBlock{
            (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if (success) {

            }
        }
```

when I want to search new friend, that the friend without in my relation, i have use below code, however, not work. have any suggestion?

```
    var resultQuery = PFQuery(className: "FriendList")
    resultQuery.whereKey("myusername", equalTo: currentUser!.username!)
    resultQuery.selectKeys(["friend"])

    var query = PFUser.query()

    query!.whereKey("username", notEqualTo: currentUser!.username!)
    query!.whereKey("objectId", doesNotMatchKey: "friend", inQuery: resultQuery)

    query!.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had modified my code when add additional field "friendusername" to keep PFUser.currentUser().username

```
        var friendListObject = PFObject(className: "FriendList")
        friendListObject.setObject(currentUser!.username!, forKey: "myusername")
        friendListObject.setObject(result.user, forKey: "friend")
        friendListObject.setObject(result.user.objectForKey("username") as! String, forKey: "friendusername")
```

when search, use friendusername for doesnotmatch, then it's work

```
var resultQuery = PFQuery(className: "FriendList")
resultQuery.whereKey("myusername", equalTo: currentUser!.username!)
resultQuery.selectKeys(["friend"])

var query = PFUser.query()

query!.whereKey("username", notEqualTo: currentUser!.username!)
query!.whereKey("objectId", doesNotMatchKey: "friend", inQuery: resultQuery)

query!.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
}
```